# how to make a one to many relation wind0ws form using visual studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm using two tables customer and orders on sql server 2012 express edition data base and I have connected it to a windows form in visual studio 2010. I've add customer table in detail view and the orders table in grid view. My problem is that I don't know how to create a relation between the two tables. I tried edit dataset and added a foreign key relation between the customer id in the customer table and the customer id in the order table. But that didn't work.

Should I make the relationship in the sql server first and the add them to the forms?

Comment: Not really sure what your question is here but if you have two tables that have a relationship then yes you should create that in the database. That is how you maintain data integrity.

Comment: basically i'm trying to create a main and detail form where when you view a customer detail you can also view the orders made by customer in the data grid view. I've done this in access and I'm new to visual studio. How do you add a image column to the data grid so i can view pictures. I have the column in varbinary(max) in sql server database, once i add the the table in data grid view it just shows an X for the image column.

Comment: Whoa look a squirrel!!! Your original question was about relationships between tables and now it is suddenly about how to store an image in sql. What is the question and what do you actually need help with?

Comment: sorry that I change my question. Thank you for your assist.

Comment: So which question(s) do you need help with?